# Is there an alternative to Adress Book that works both on a Macbook or Imac *and* on Iphone?

Tags: iphone, contacts

Is there an alternative to Adress Book that works both on a Macbook or Imac *and* on Iphone? I always get stuck on managing contact groups on all my apple devices. Or is there a strategy to keep contacts data consistent on 3 apple devices at the same time. I'd rather like to do it without cloud services due to privacy concerns.

*edit for clarification:*

I use an imac (Snow Leopoard, early 2008) at home, a MBP (early 2010, Lion) for work and an Iphone 4 (iOS 5).

When i try to sync my contacts or groups of contacts from the iPhone to the MBP, it's not working. But the other way round it's possible, although i have to overwrite all existing contacts.

With the iMac it works great. Both ways.

Comment: Could you maybe indicate what is wrong with Address Book such that people will know what you're looking for in a contacts managing app?

Comment: How do you plan on keeping contact data consistent between three devices at the same time *without* using some type of online service?

Comment: @daGUY : With my Nokia 6300 I can sync my contacts with my MacBook via Bluetooth not using any cloud services but just using iSync. If I would have another computer (say an iMac) I would sync the Nokia to the iMac and then all would be in-sync. Maybe there's a similar way with iPhones.

Comment: @BartArondson: I don't think iSync exists anymore, as of OS X Lion.

Comment: @daGUY: I'm aware of that, but the OP doesn't state what his OS is (@Volker: please state what your OS is). If it's Lion [here](http://slashusr.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/the-missing-isync-in-os-x-lion-and-what-to-do-about-it/) is a way to get iSync on Lion.

Comment: @daGUY with "at the same time" i don't mean in real time, rather more in a "coexistent" meaning. I'm not  speaking native english, sorry for irritation.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are getting stuck managing your contact groups. What is the problem you're expiriencing with Address Book?

Comment: sync contacts from: 
Imac -> Iphone = works; 
Iphone -> Imac = works; 
Iphone -> Macbook = not working at all, neither contacts nor groups; 
Macbook -> Iphone = works, but only if all contacts on Iphone get deleted by itunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Cobook?

http://www.cobookapp.com

There's a mac app and an iPhone app
AND 
it's free!